# sklearn classification report

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, sklearn-pandas

I am training an electra model with tensorflow on a multi label task. The ROC performance of each individual label is

```
AUROC per tag
morality_binary: 0.8840802907943726
emotion_binary: 0.8690611124038696
positive_binary: 0.9115268588066101
negative_binary: 0.9200447201728821
care_binary: 0.9266915321350098
fairness_binary: 0.8638730645179749
authority_binary: 0.8471786379814148
sanctity_binary: 0.9040042757987976
harm_binary: 0.9046630859375
injustice_binary: 0.8968375325202942
betrayal_binary: 0.846387505531311
subversion_binary: 0.7741811871528625
degradation_binary: 0.9601025581359863
```

But when I run the the sklearn classification report:

```
THRESHOLD = 0.5

y_pred = predictions.numpy()
y_true = labels.numpy()

upper, lower = 1, 0

y_pred = np.where(y_pred > THRESHOLD, upper, lower)

print(classification_report(
  y_true, 
  y_pred, 
  target_names=LABEL_COLUMNS, 
  zero_division=0
))
```

... five of the labels turns out with an f-score of 0:

```
                    precision    recall  f1-score   support

   morality_binary       0.72      0.73      0.73       347
    emotion_binary       0.66      0.73      0.69       303
   positive_binary       0.71      0.76      0.73       242
   negative_binary       0.70      0.62      0.65       141
       care_binary       0.67      0.60      0.63       141
   fairness_binary       0.55      0.53      0.54       166
  authority_binary       0.00      0.00      0.00        49
   sanctity_binary       0.00      0.00      0.00        23
       harm_binary       0.48      0.32      0.39        50
  injustice_binary       0.62      0.56      0.59        97
   betrayal_binary       0.00      0.00      0.00        30
 subversion_binary       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
degradation_binary       0.00      0.00      0.00        10
```

Can someone explain to me how this is possible? I can understand a low f-score, but 0?

Answer (score 2):

*I assume 0 is negative and 1 is positive.*

AUROC calculates the area under the ROC curve as a measure of how well a classifier performs (0.5 score is a random, coin-flip model). To draw the ROC curve, you need to calculate two values at different threshold values to distinguish positive from negative examples.

- y-axis: True positive rate (TPR) - How many of the positive examples did the model predict as negative.
- x-axis: False positive rate (FPR) - How many of the negative examples did the model predict as positive.

TPR is also called recall. We calculate this using the following formula:

> TPR = True positives / (True positives + False Negatives)
> = True positives / All positives

So the only way TPR can be 0 is because TP is also 0. This means that precision will also be 0 as we calculate precision using the following formula:

> Precision = True positives / (True positives + False positives)

Which will also result in 0 if and only if TP is equal to 0.

Now given the ROC curve ([Roc curve shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeiME.png)), if FPR is 0, the area under the curve will also be equal to 0. This is because you have picked a single threshold value (0.5) in your code to predict 0 or 1. This is not a representation of the ROC curve and AUROC measure.

I suggest you take a look at the ROC curve and try different values for you classification threshold. The resulting AUROC values suggest that your model performs better than a random one in general, so you should find a good threshold.

---